# Последняя итерация цикла

Tags: алгоритм, golang

как при помощи if "поймать" последнюю итерацию цикла for,  если сам цикл задан так:

```
for i, variable := range result.Variables {
   ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Пример для списка**

Легко, как и в любом другом языке: `если индекс == длина_списка - 1`. Пример:

```
func main() {
    values := [...]string{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"}
    for i, variable := range values {
        if i == len(values)-1 {
            fmt.Println(variable)
        }
    }
}
```

[Запустить код](https://play.golang.org/p/tJt1DSY4vqs)

---

**Для словаря со счётчиком**

```
func main() {
    values := map[string]int{
        "pi": 31415,
        "e": 27182,
        "phi": 16180,
    }
    i := 0
    for _, variable := range values {
        if i == len(values)-1 {
            fmt.Println(variable)
        }
        i += 1
    }
}
```

[Запустить код](https://play.golang.org/p/0B9V4aWOM1d)

---

**Пример для словаря с итерацией по списку ключей**

```
func main() {
    values := map[string]int{
        "pi": 31415,
        "e": 27182,
        "phi": 16180,
    }
    keys := reflect.ValueOf(values).MapKeys()
    for i, key := range keys {
        if i == len(keys)-1 {
            fmt.Println(values[key.Interface().(string)])
        }
    }
}
```

[Запустить код](https://play.golang.org/p/87Jt5XeaVFt)

Comment: Автор не уточняет конечно, но у него может быть и мапа с неинтовыми ключами.

Comment: @u_mulder в таком случае можно итерироваться по ключам или самостоятельно хранить количество обработанных элементов. Если автор спросит, допишу.

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что перемещение по мапе рандомизировано, и для неё "последняя итерация" может быть в принципе полезна, но нужно чётко понимать, что там не будет привязки к конкретному элементу.

Comment: Также докумнетнация на `MapKeys` говорит, что «MapKeys returns a slice containing all the keys present in the map, _in unspecified order.»,_ то есть вариант с рефлектом ничего не добавляет к простому `if ... range мапа`.

Comment: @kostix Мне кажется, это очевидная информация :) По умолчанию словари/мапы почти во всех языках не упорядоченные.

Comment: Надеюсь, это никого не обидит, но как по мне, исходный вопрос подразумевает пока ещё не оч. сильное владение программированием, то есть очевидность работы мапы тут не очень очевидна ;)